# How can I catch a screen capture event on android devices?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to be able to catch the event of a screen capture in order to use the captured image in my application.
Is it possible?
Right now I'm just monitoring the screen capture folder which is a very bad way of doing this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

Not directly, at least in any documented/supported form. For example, there is no documented broadcast `Intent` indicating that a screenshot was taken.

Comment: in this case how would you recommend doing it?
Is there some kind of a document for what folder every vendor use for screen captures?

Comment: @RotemSlootzky: I doubt that it is documented. That being said, once Android started offering user-initiated screenshots (I forget which of the 4.x releases added that), most vendors probably have not changed that location. I haven't played with the screenshots recently myself, so I forget where they are placed.